# NLog - how to configure to conditionally write to Database and on exception to Email and on exception to File

Tags: c#, winforms, nlog

Previously I had built a logging class where I could choose Either to write to an Oracle database (as a separate connection), or if there was an exception to then send a SMTP email, or if that had an exception to write to a physical file (using the `DefaultLogWriter` from the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Logging` namespace).

Now that I am writing a new `WinForms` application where the database is SQL Server ... and because Transactions are handled differently vs Oracle ... I wanted to use `NLog` (because of its pre-built ability to write to always run outside of transaction).

When calling an instantiated object of `NLog.Logger` defined as

```
private static readonly NLog.Logger Logger = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
```

is it possible for the call to `Logger.<LogLevel>` to be configured so that exceptions roll downhill (ex. 1st try the Database, 2nd try sending an email, 3rd write to a file)?

Thanks for your time and any suggestions you offer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think FallBackGroup is what you are looking for:

https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/FallbackGroup-target

Comment: Not downvoted it, but maybe add a (relevant) example?

Comment: PS the https://docs.nlog-project.org/ is old and a tryout. It should be removed

Comment: @PhilSandler - per https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-file#troubleshooting-logging it is recommended to not have throwExceptions set to "True" when the code is ran in production.  Does that mean that NLog has code to determine when there is a Database exception AND then determine from that exception to fall back to sending to an email (and if there is an exception with sending an email it would fall back to writing to a file on the network)?  And if so ... does NLog expose if such exceptions occur?

Comment: @user13116244 I'm sorry--I'm not sure I understand your question.  I don't think there is any relationship or dependency between FallBackGroup and throwExceptions.  ThrowExceptions=true means that a problem when trying to log (or during load of config) will actually raise an exception, something you rarely, if ever, want in production.

Comment: @PhilSandler - Have you used the FallBackGroup?  It may be what I am looking for ... but I was wondering if you (OR anyone else) have witnessed how NLog handles exceptions (ex. no connection to the database, and failure to connect or send an email).  I am looking for a reassurance that NLog will handle such issues.   Thanks.

Comment: @user13116244 We never used it, though we looked into it once which is why the question caught my attention.  I would recommend doing some googling and some tinkering.  :)

Comment: The fallback group works with throwExceptions = false. Otherwise it would be pointless ;)

Comment: Thanks for everyone's input.  Until I have the time to test this thoroughly ... I won't keep this question "open" any longer.  It sounds like FallBackGroup may be what I am looking for.  Now I wonder if a FallBackGroup can be nested within another?